# A pair of MOLS of order 15?

Tags: combinatorics, finite-fields, latin-square

Is there any place where I can find a pair of MOLS(mutually orthogonal latin squares) of order 15? I can't seem to find a place where it's spelled out explicitly.

Comment: -1 Please think about previous answers before asking new questions on the same subject.  What does this have to do with finite fields?  There are mutually orthogonal Latin squares of orders that have no fields (10, for example).

Comment: A finite field $F$ of $q$ elements generates $q-1$ MOLS following the recipe $L_\alpha(x,y)=\alpha x+y$ for all $\alpha\in F^*$, $x,y\in F$. If $F'$ is another finite field with $q'$ elements, then the Cartesian products 
$$L_{\alpha,\alpha'}((x,x'),(y,y'))=(\alpha x+y,\alpha'x'+y'),$$
with $x,y$ (resp. $x',y'$) ranging over their respective fields, are Latin squares of size $qq'$. If $q\neq q'$, $\alpha_1\neq\alpha_2$, $\alpha_1'\neq\alpha_2'$, then the squares $L_{\alpha_1,\alpha_1'}$ and $L_{\alpha_2,\alpha_2'}$ are orthogonal. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any odd $n$, a diagonally cyclic Latin square construction works.  Here's [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code that implements it:

```
n:=15;

# Diagonally cyclic Latin square
L:=List([1..n],i->List([1..n],j->0));
for j in [1..n] do L[1][j]:=((2*(j-1)) mod n)+1; od;
for i in [2..n] do for j in [1..n] do L[i][j]:=(L[i-1][((j-2) mod n)+1] mod n)+1; od; od;
L;

# Fixed diagonal Latin square
M:=List([1..n],i->List([1..n],j->((j-i) mod n)+1));
M;
```

and this is what the output looks like:

```
gap> L;
[ [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14 ], 
  [ 15, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 ], 
  [ 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 ], 
  [ 13, 15, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 ], 
  [ 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ], 
  [ 11, 13, 15, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ], 
  [ 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 2, 4, 6, 8 ], 
  [ 9, 11, 13, 15, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7 ], 
  [ 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 2, 4, 6 ], 
  [ 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5 ], 
  [ 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 2, 4 ], 
  [ 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3 ], 
  [ 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 2 ], 
  [ 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1 ], 
  [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 ] ]
```

and

```
gap> M;
[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ], 
  [ 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ], 
  [ 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 ], 
  [ 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ], 
  [ 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ], 
  [ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ], 
  [ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], 
  [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ], 
  [ 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ], 
  [ 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ], 
  [ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], 
  [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4 ], 
  [ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3 ], 
  [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2 ], 
  [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1 ] ]
```

We can readily see that they're orthogonal (the forwards broken diagonals of the first square are $1,2,\ldots,n$ cyclically permuted, whereas the forwards broken diagonals of the second are $x,x,\ldots,x$, for some $x$).  The only thing we should check is that the first square is always a Latin square, which comes from its first row being an [orthomorphism](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orthomorphism.html).

Answer (score 2):

Natalia Makarova has built a MOLS group of order 15, consisting of four Latin squares. The topic is discussed in detail on [her webpage](http://www.natalimak1.narod.ru/mols15.htm), and I will also quote the squares below. They also built a MODLS of order 15 on [page dedicated to MODLS](http://www.natalimak1.narod.ru/diagon.htm).

Whether a group of MODLS of order 15 containing more than 4 squares is still an open question.

```
1 7 12 10 9 3 15 6 5 13 4 11 14 2 8
3 2 8 13 11 10 4 15 7 6 14 5 12 1 9
2 4 3 9 14 12 11 5 15 8 7 1 6 13 10
14 3 5 4 10 1 13 12 6 15 9 8 2 7 11
8 1 4 6 5 11 2 14 13 7 15 10 9 3 12
4 9 2 5 7 6 12 3 1 14 8 15 11 10 13
11 5 10 3 6 8 7 13 4 2 1 9 15 12 14
13 12 6 11 4 7 9 8 14 5 3 2 10 15 1
15 14 13 7 12 5 8 10 9 1 6 4 3 11 2
12 15 1 14 8 13 6 9 11 10 2 7 5 4 3
5 13 15 2 1 9 14 7 10 12 11 3 8 6 4
7 6 14 15 3 2 10 1 8 11 13 12 4 9 5
10 8 7 1 15 4 3 11 2 9 12 14 13 5 6
6 11 9 8 2 15 5 4 12 3 10 13 1 14 7
9 10 11 12 13 14 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 15

1 11 8 3 6 12 9 4 13 15 5 10 2 7 14
8 2 12 9 4 7 13 10 5 14 15 6 11 3 1
4 9 3 13 10 5 8 14 11 6 1 15 7 12 2
13 5 10 4 14 11 6 9 1 12 7 2 15 8 3
9 14 6 11 5 1 12 7 10 2 13 8 3 15 4
15 10 1 7 12 6 2 13 8 11 3 14 9 4 5
5 15 11 2 8 13 7 3 14 9 12 4 1 10 6
11 6 15 12 3 9 14 8 4 1 10 13 5 2 7
3 12 7 15 13 4 10 1 9 5 2 11 14 6 8
7 4 13 8 15 14 5 11 2 10 6 3 12 1 9
2 8 5 14 9 15 1 6 12 3 11 7 4 13 10
14 3 9 6 1 10 15 2 7 13 4 12 8 5 11
6 1 4 10 7 2 11 15 3 8 14 5 13 9 12
10 7 2 5 11 8 3 12 15 4 9 1 6 14 13
12 13 14 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 15

1 9 7 13 3 2 12 10 6 11 14 4 15 8 5
9 2 10 8 14 4 3 13 11 7 12 1 5 15 6
15 10 3 11 9 1 5 4 14 12 8 13 2 6 7
7 15 11 4 12 10 2 6 5 1 13 9 14 3 8
4 8 15 12 5 13 11 3 7 6 2 14 10 1 9
2 5 9 15 13 6 14 12 4 8 7 3 1 11 10
12 3 6 10 15 14 7 1 13 5 9 8 4 2 11
3 13 4 7 11 15 1 8 2 14 6 10 9 5 12
6 4 14 5 8 12 15 2 9 3 1 7 11 10 13
11 7 5 1 6 9 13 15 3 10 4 2 8 12 14
13 12 8 6 2 7 10 14 15 4 11 5 3 9 1
10 14 13 9 7 3 8 11 1 15 5 12 6 4 2
5 11 1 14 10 8 4 9 12 2 15 6 13 7 3
8 6 12 2 1 11 9 5 10 13 3 15 7 14 4
14 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 15

1 6 13 7 12 5 8 14 11 4 2 15 10 9 3
10 2 7 14 8 13 6 9 1 12 5 3 15 11 4
12 11 3 8 1 9 14 7 10 2 13 6 4 15 5
15 13 12 4 9 2 10 1 8 11 3 14 7 5 6
6 15 14 13 5 10 3 11 2 9 12 4 1 8 7
9 7 15 1 14 6 11 4 12 3 10 13 5 2 8
3 10 8 15 2 1 7 12 5 13 4 11 14 6 9
7 4 11 9 15 3 2 8 13 6 14 5 12 1 10
2 8 5 12 10 15 4 3 9 14 7 1 6 13 11
14 3 9 6 13 11 15 5 4 10 1 8 2 7 12
8 1 4 10 7 14 12 15 6 5 11 2 9 3 13
4 9 2 5 11 8 1 13 15 7 6 12 3 10 14
11 5 10 3 6 12 9 2 14 15 8 7 13 4 1
5 12 6 11 4 7 13 10 3 1 15 9 8 14 2
13 14 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 15
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greco-Latin_square) on Greco-Latin squares shows squares of order 3 and 5.  Gerry Myerson gave an answer to your question [/mutually-orthogonal-latin-squares-of-order-mn-from-order-m-and-order-n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170149/mutually-orthogonal-latin-squares-of-order-mn-from-order-m-and-order-n) which shows how to make one.  What don't you understand?

Answer (score -1):

If n, m1 and m2 are such that 1=(n,m1)=(n,m2)=(n, m1-m2) then the LS 
given by x+m1y, x+m2y on Z_n are MOLS.
For n=15 you can take m1=1, m2=2 or m1=2, m2=4, etc

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: Could you explain how you came to this result.  Its very helpful to people reading your answer if you give not just the result but how that result was derived as this gives people a way to give more general answers.  It might also be helpful if you explain the notation used in this case.